# Path to access to external memory on samsung galaxy

Tags: android, file, sd-card

I am struggling with this issue all day... all i want is to read file from external memory card on my galaxy version 4.1.2, but on the end i figured out that with this path

```
 Environment. getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

is giving me back path of internal memory. 
How can I access file from this card? I copied doc file on card and want to read it.

Comment: External storage is not officially supported in Android. You'll need to find the mount points yourself, and possibly make it custom for each manufacturer -- possibly even per device. There are a few hacks out there if you search.

Comment: try hardcoding the path like /sdcard/myFile.docx softwares like esfileexplorer will show the physical path. If the physical path doesnot work then you are doomed lol

Comment: All i want is to try to open en existing document by giving apsoluth path. Can I put doc somewhere else? I tried to assets and raw folder.

Comment: what is wrong with saving the path somewhere when you saved the file then just reference the path for that file when you want it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2833783/illegal-argumentu  put this in answere. I did it.